# MongooseJS post reference creation

Tags: mongoose

Please can one assist me Here I want to create a report that will include the vehicule, however, my result is coming as expected.

fist file is below

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var reportSchema = new Schema({

    reportDate : { type: Date, default: Date.now},
    description: { type: String, required: true},
    address: String,
    vehicule : [{type: String, ref: 'Vehicule'}], 
    user : [{type: String, ref: 'User'}] 


})

 var Vehicule = mongoose.model('Report', ReportSchema);

 module.exports = Report;
```

The second schema for the report is below but when I create a report it is not including the vehicule id within report. The vehicule is coming back as an empty array. any help will be much appreciated

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var VehiculeSchema = new Schema({

    make: String,
    model: String,
    color:String,
    year: String,
    vin: {type: String, required:true, unique:true},
    imagePath: String,

    user : [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]




    }, 



      { timestamps: true 

 });

 var Vehicule = mongoose.model('Vehicule', VehiculeSchema);

 module.exports = Vehicule;
```

Below is the method I am using to create the report

```
 var Vehicule = require('../models/vehicule');
 var Report = require('../models/report');
 var User = require('../models/user');


 exports.newReport = function(req, res, next){



   req.body.user = req.user;
   req.body.vehicule = req.vehicule;



   var report = new Report({description :req.body.description, address:      req.body.address, user: req.user, vehicule: req.vehicule});


   report.save(function(err, data){

      if(err){

          return next(err);

           res.json({message: "cannot add this report"});

       }else {

           res.json({message: "report added", data: report})
           console.log(JSON.stringify((data)))
       }
   });



}
```

Below is the result I am getting back, I wonder what I am missing and why it is not working.
       {
    "message": "report added",
     "data": {
    "__v": 0,
      "description": "This is  error another",
      "address": "Quatier  vill",
      "_id": "58af4e857ae6770a7d68d85a",
      "user": [
        "{ _id: 58a7315e0a9f6474a88766fa, role: 'creator' }"
       ],
       "vehicule": [],
       "reportDate": "2017-02-23T21:05:09.384Z"
     }
  }

Answer (score 0):

below is the solution i  come up with and it is working

```
  var Vehicule = require('../models/vehicule');
  var Report = require('../models/report');
  var User = require('../models/user');


  exports.newReport = function(req, res){

    req.body.user = req.user;
  // req.body.vehicule = req.vehicule;
    var vehic = new Vehicule(req.body);



    var report = new Report({description:req.body.description, address:      req.body.address, vehicule: vehic._id, user: req.user });

     report.save(function(err){

      if(err){

          return
           res.json({message: "cannot add this report"});
           res.send(err);
       }else {
           return
           res.json({message: "report added", data: report})

       }
   });


 }
```